# What version of Java is CloudHub using?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, cloudhub

Can anyone tell me what version of Java the various versions of CloudHub are running?  I'm guessing there's a document somewhere that details as much, but I haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of any doc specifying this, but I can see that *as of today*, CloudHub runs with: `1.6.0_24 Vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.`.

Comment: Thanks, David, I didn't see this answer until today.  Where did find the info above?  Do you know if it applies to all of the versions of CloudHub available today (3.2.2 - 3.3.2)?

Comment: I see this from the logs in my CH instances. You'll notice that this JDK is **not** in the list of officially recommended JDKs for Mule: https://github.com/mulesoft/mule/blob/mule-3.x/pom.xml#L1647 so... this is probably subject to change at any time.