# CloudHub unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Tags: mule-studio, cloudhub

I have implemented and tested a simple REST example within Mulesoft, which is working correctly on the local server.

As a second step I want to deploy it on CloudHub, which is directly possible from emule ESB studio.

> **On the CloudHub log I get the following error:**

```
null
org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested PropertyAccessException details (1) are:
PropertyAccessException 1:
org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException:
Property 'objectClassName' threw 
exception;
nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: com/rest/test/HelloREST 
: **Unsupported major.minor version 51.0**
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:1145)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl.java:902)
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:75)
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:57)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1424)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1132)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522).
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cloudhub runs java 6 as Dossot answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15646388/what-version-of-java-is-cloudhub-using)

You should compile your code wit that target.

Comment: Thanks was I already solved. Your answer is correct anyway :)